# How can i link a canvas on a grid, to the mainwindow.xaml?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a canvas in a grid, i want to keep my canvas on that grid, because its the first window, that opens in my program.

In my MainWindow.xaml, i have a `ContentPage`, that always changes its content, the startup content is the authenticationPage. In this page i have a `Canvas` that shows my skeletal tracking, and is used for making a gesture. This `gestureCanvas` is on my `authenticationPage`. The code behind this `gestureCanvas` is on my MainWindow.xaml.cs.

I need to link the `gestureCanvas` with my MainWindow.xaml.cs, because the code is behind `MainWindow`, and it's going to be used there, because it's an Kinect application.

How to link these ?

```
partial class MainWindow
{
    void LoadCircleGestureDetector()
    {
        using (Stream recordStream = File.Open(circleKBPath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        {
            circleGestureRecognizer.TraceTo(gesturesCanvas, Colors.Red);
        }
    }
 }
```

This is my authenticationPage

```
         <UserControl
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:smartHome2011"
xmlns:MyUserControl="clr-namespace:MyUserControl;assembly=MyUserControl"
mc:Ignorable="d"
x:Class="smartHome2011.AuthenticationPage"
x:Name="UserControl"
d:DesignWidth="640" d:DesignHeight="480">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
         <Grid x:Name="kinectGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <Viewbox Margin="204,220,430,220">
                <Grid ClipToBounds="True" Margin="204,220,430,220">
                    **<Canvas x:Name="gesturesCanvas" />**
                    <Canvas x:Name="kinectCanvas"></Canvas>
                </Grid>
            </Viewbox>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: I can not understand your question. Can you add your MainWindow.xaml.cs Code??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at your code behind MainWindow you can try following

```
var gesturesCanvas = YourContentPage.FindName("gesturesCanvas") as Canvas;
if (gesturesCanvas != null) {
  // do something
}
```

hope this helps

Comment: sorry i changed the canvas into grid, i want to show this gesture canvas in my mainwindow hwo do i call this ?